# Prestashop - can't upgrade

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

Hi I wanted to install "1-Click Upgrade v1.6.7 - by PrestaShop" plugin, but I'm not able to because of the following error:

```
The following module(s) were not installed properly:
autoupgrade : 
    Unable to create the "AdminSelfUpgrade" tab
```

I have checked enabled modules and all of them are up to date and issued by PrestaShop. Could anybody help me, please?

I'm currently running PrestaShop™ 1.6.0.11.

Thanks for your help.

**UPDATE:** Turned on Error reporting:

```
[PrestaShopDatabaseException]

Unknown column 'hide_host_mode' in 'field list'


INSERT INTO `ps_tab` (`id_parent`, `position`, `module`, `class_name`, `active`, `hide_host_mode`) VALUES ('17', '10', 'autoupgrade', 'AdminSelfUpgrade', '1', '0')

at line 639 in file classes/db/Db.php
634.            WebserviceRequest::getInstance()->setError(500, '[SQL Error] '.$this->getMsgError().'. From '.(isset($dbg[3]['class']) ? $dbg[3]['class'] : '').'->'.$dbg[3]['function'].'() Query was : '.$sql, 97);
635.        }
636.        elseif (_PS_DEBUG_SQL_ && $errno && !defined('PS_INSTALLATION_IN_PROGRESS'))
637.        {
638.            if ($sql)
639.                throw new PrestaShopDatabaseException($this->getMsgError().'<br /><br /><pre>'.$sql.'</pre>');
640.            throw new PrestaShopDatabaseException($this->getMsgError());
641.        }
642.    }
643. 
644.    /**
DbCore->displayError - [line 333 - classes/db/Db.php] - [1 Arguments]
DbCore->query - [line 613 - classes/db/Db.php] - [1 Arguments]
DbCore->q - [line 398 - classes/db/Db.php] - [2 Arguments]
DbCore->insert - [line 480 - classes/ObjectModel.php] - [3 Arguments]
ObjectModelCore->add - [line 103 - classes/Tab.php] - [2 Arguments]
TabCore->add - [line 442 - classes/ObjectModel.php] - [2 Arguments]
ObjectModelCore->save - [line 115 - classes/Tab.php]
TabCore->save - [line 74 - modules/autoupgrade/autoupgrade.php]
Autoupgrade->install - [line 828 - controllers/admin/AdminModulesController.php]
AdminModulesControllerCore->postProcessCallback - [line 1071 - controllers/admin/AdminModulesController.php]
AdminModulesControllerCore->postProcess - [line 171 - classes/controller/Controller.php]
ControllerCore->run - [line 374 - classes/Dispatcher.php]
DispatcherCore->dispatch - [line 54 - admin/index.php]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have solved it myself: There was a missing column in the `ps_tab`.

To fix it, you need to go to this MySQL table and add `hide_host_mode` column into the DV, it's a `tinyint` type.

Answer (score 1):

it would be a good idea if you turn on [Error Reporting](https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/224525-how-to-turn-on-error-reporting-for-debug-information-blank-page-500-internal-server-error/).

Also, do you have installed some 3rd party module that manage the admin tabs? Or at least a module that manage admin staff?

If that, try to uninstall it and delete the directory files.

Comment: Thanks, I have turned the Error Reporting ON. The log is added to my post. I have no idea what is third party plugin, but all plugins come from PrestaShop. (I'm sorry)